# AHK: Using RandomBezier Function

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm trying to use RandomBezier.ahk (https://github.com/MasterFocus/AutoHotkey/tree/master/Functions/RandomBezier) to randomize the mouse path to click on things in game.
The Example.ahk in that github works for me, but when trying to use it in my own program, it doesn't work when calling the RandomBezier function.
I have the files in the same local directory.

Any help on getting this function to work?
Thanks

```
#SingleInstance force
#Include RandomBezier.ahk

^j::
screenWidth := A_ScreenWidth
screenHeight := A_ScreenHeight

//I'm using ratios so that I'm not hardcoding based on a given display resolution
Play_X := floor(0.02604*A_ScreenWidth)
Play_Y := floor(0.37037*A_ScreenHeight)
RandomBezier(0, 0, %Play_X%, %Play_Y%, "T1200 RO RD OT100 OB-100 OL0 OR0 P4-3") //<-- this line doesn't do anything. the mouse doesn't move.
;MouseMove, %Play_X%, %Play_Y%, 10 <--this line works, so I know that the variables Play_X, Play_Y works 
Sleep 50
Click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic mistake of trying to use legacy syntax in a place where it doesn't belong (though I'd argue it no longer belongs anywhere whatsoever).
Function parameters are passed in as expressions, not as legacy text parameters.
So instead of legacy way of referencing a variable
`RandomBezier(0, 0, %Play_X%, %Play_Y%,`,
you do
`RandomBezier(0, 0, Play_X, Play_Y,`.

Overall I'd recommend you to try to to get rid of legacy syntax. It's not 2008 anymore.
Reading this page on the documentation is a good start to learning the difference
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm